# Was Nepal formed by a Hindu saint called Ne Muni?

Tags: saint

This [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nepal#cite_note-168) article claims that

> As it is believed that Ne Muni established Nepal, some important
>   priests in Nepal are called "Tirthaguru Nemuni"

Is there any more details available about the saint? Do any scriptures mention him?

Comment: Wikipedia claims it's mentioned in the Skanda Purana, but it doesn't say where in the Skanda Purana.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. According to legends of Nepal, Nepal was named after a saint named **Nemi Muni** or **Ne Muni**.

Wikipedia says the following about etymology of Nepal. From the same article as:

> According to the Skanda Purana, a rishi called "Nemi" used to live in the Himalayas. In the Pashupati Purana, he is mentioned as a saint and a protector. He is said to have practised meditation at the Bagmati and Kesavati rivers and to have taught there.

It doesn't mention where in Skanda Purana this story of Nemi occurs. But there is a text called Pashupati Purana which gives history of Nepal and legends associated with rivers Bagmati and Kesavati. According to this text, Ne Muni was appointed as the ruler and protector of Nepal. Henceforth, the region was known as Nepal. Even though the details of this text is not known much, it is quoted in some of the books related to royal dynasties which ruled Nepal. One such statement which gives the etymology and history of the word Nepal.

> The history of Nepal goes back to remote antiquity. The country derives its name from a saint called Ne (or Nemuni) who lived at one time in Nepal. **In the *Pashupati Purana* Sanat Kumar speaks out, “A saint named Ne had protected him at one time by his meritorious works: thus it is that the country in the heart of the Himalayas called Nepal”**. The Nepal Mahatmya also mentions the said Nemi, **‘O Nemi, says Pashupati to him, “walk at the head of the saints of this sacred domain; it is you who must, O Treasure of austerities, protect this country on my word”,and since then
>   the country has been called Nepal**. Dr. Wright supports the above view and
>   observes that the great Rishi performed his devotions at the junction of the
>   Bagmati and Keshavati and by the blessing of Swayambhu and Bajrajogi
>   he instructed the people in the true path of religion and also ruled over the country.

Above text is from [*The Life and Times of Maharaja Juddha Shumsher Jung Bahadur Rana of Nepal*](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/The_Life_and_Times_of_Maharaja_Juddha_Sh.html?id=yEvbH8Fv-boC&redir_esc=y), biography of Joodha Shamsher Jung Bahadur Rana who ruled Nepal.